# Nginx - [warn] An upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/7/08/0000000087

Tags: nginx

Nginx is reverse proxy for my website and sometimes the website has malfunctions that leads to error pages.

I restarted my application like so:
`systemctl restart myapplication.service`
and it didn't help.

Then I restarted sql service like so
`systemctl restart mssql-server`
and it didn't help.

Then I restarted `Nginx` service like so
`systemctl restart nginx`
and vualla the website works again.

So I looked at nginx error log and tried to figure out the problem and I saw thousands lines of these warning:

> [warn] 31507#31507: *4839 an upstream response is buffered to a
>   temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/2/20/0000000202 while
>   reading upstream

This is the configuration in my **default.conf** file:

```
server {
    #listen        80;
    listen                 *:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate        /etc/ssl/example.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/example.key;
    server_name            example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://localhost:7001/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I read the answer that was given [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/587386/an-upstream-response-is-buffered-to-a-temporary-file) that suggests to set the `proxy_max_temp_file_size` to `0` but that doesn't make sense to me because if the buffer is full it writes to temp file so why should I limit it to 0?

Other option that I am considering is to increase the buffer size from the defaults but I am not if I should.
It says:

> Syntax:   proxy_buffer_size size;
>  Default:     proxy_buffer_size 4k|8k;
>   Context:  http, server, location 
> Sets the size of the buffer used for
>   reading the first part of the response received from the proxied
>   server. This part usually contains a small response header. By
>   default, the buffer size is equal to one memory page. This is either
>   4K or 8K, depending on a platform. It can be made smaller, however.

What should I do?